# Any set of $d$ points in a projective space is the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d-1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is an exercise from Harris' "Algebraic geometry: A First Course":

Let $\Gamma\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a finite set of $d$ points, not all on the same line. Show that $\Gamma$ is the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d-1$ or lower.

Here's a proof I came up with: Let us consider the set of all distinct lines, passing through each pair of distinct points in $\Gamma$. Then for each point let us consider all lines in that set that pass through it, $V(L_i)$, and let's take the product of forms that define them, $\Pi_i L_i$. Then the common zeroes of such products are precisely the points in $\Gamma$.

This proof doesn't quite work however in the case of points in general position. For example, if we take 4 points on the plane in general position, then there is an extra point in which the diagonals intersect. An obvious way to avoid is to not consider the diagonals at all. But what will then be a procedure for choosing the lines $V(L_i)$ as above?

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree here. Hint: Lagrange interpolation. (I think there was a solved version of this on here at some point, but I can't find it via search yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by the OP, I'm converting my comment in to an answer.

Hint: Lagrange interpolation.