# Exercise 1.3 in Harris' Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am a beginner in Algebraic Geometry and was recommended to read Harris' Book about the subject. I am, however, stuck on the first exercise:

> Show that if $\Gamma$ consists of $d$ points and is not contained in a
> line, then $\Gamma$ may be described as the zero locus of polynomials
> of degree $d-1$ and less.

Upon further research, the only useful hint I have found is that I am supposed to use Lagrange Interpolation ([Any set of $d$ points in a projective space is the zero locus of polynomials of degree $d-1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999283/any-set-of-d-points-in-a-projective-space-is-the-zero-locus-of-polynomials-of)). I have thus far been unable to apply it here. Could anyone please help me and explain it in an understandable manner?

Thank you!

Comment: @hm2020 I quoted the exercise (word by word). Though how I understand it, you have got it right; only the polynomial in question should be homogeneous as the finite subset is a variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: I meant to write the following: "You should give the complete formulation of the exercise. If $Γ⊆\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a "finite set of points" (we do not speak of "multiplicity"), its ideal $I(Γ)⊆k[x_0,..,x_n]$ is defined and its homogeneous coordinate ring is by definition $S(Γ):=k[x_i]/I(Γ)$. Is the exercise saying that the ideal $I(Γ)$ can be generated by homogeneous polynomials of degree $≤d−1$?"

Comment: I interpret the exercise as follows: Show that there are homogeneous polynomials of degree $\leq d-1$ that generate a homogeneous ideal $I$. The projective variety associated to this ideal $I$ (i.e. the common zeros of the ideal) will equal to $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider the easier task of obtaining $\Gamma$ as the zero-locus of a family of polynomials of degree $d$ or less: If $q \not \in \Gamma$ and $p \in \Gamma$ there exists a hyperplane $H_p$ such that $p \in H_p$ and $q \not \in H_p$. Let $L_p$ be a homogenous polynomial of degree one that cuts out $H_p$. Choose such an $L_p$ for a every $p \in \Gamma$ and define a polynomial of degree $d$, $F_q = \Pi_{p \in \Gamma}L_p$. Then $\Gamma$ is the zero-locus of the family $(F_q)_{q \in \Bbb{P}^n - \Gamma}$.

Under the additional hypothesis that $\Gamma$ is not contained in a line the construction above can modified to yield a family of polynomials of degree $d-1$. Here follows a sketch of the steps:

1. If $q \not \in \Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ is not contained in a line, show that there exists distinct points $r,s \in \Gamma$ such that $q$ is not contained in the line through $r$ and $s$.
2. With $r, s, q$ as in 1, show that there is a hyperplane $H$ such that $r,s \in H$ and $q \not \in H$. This means there is a degree one polynomial $L$ such that $L(r)=L(s)=0$ and $L(q) \not = 0$.
3. Use $L$ found in step 2 to construct a polynomial $\tilde{F}_q$ of degree $d-1$ such that $\tilde{F}_q(q) \not = 0$ and $\tilde{F}_q(p) = 0$ for all $p \in \Gamma$.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your answer and help!
1.: w.l.o.g one can take 3 distinct points $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \Gamma$ (as $\Gamma$ has to contain at least three points). Now take a point $q\not\in\Gamma$ and look at the unique line between $a_1,a_2$. If $q$ is on that line, then look at the line $a_1,a_3$ which cannot coincide with that line per assumption. $q$ cannot lie on that line as the only intersection point is $a_1$. Thus, the selection of $r,q$ and $s$ is possible

Comment: 2.: According to a definiton of a line: A projective line is given through $n-1$ homogeneous linear forms. As $q\not\in L$, there exists at least one homogeneous linear form $H$ s.t. $H(q)\neq 0$. So now look at the hyperplane that is the zero locus of this homogeneous linear form: It contains $r,s$ but not $q$. Thus, we have found a degree one polynomial $L$ s.t. $L(r)=L(s)=0,\ L(q)\neq0$.

Comment: 3.: Now repeat this process $d-1$ times s.t. every point of $\Gamma$ is covered at least once. Then you get $d-1$ distinct polynomials of degree one. Upon taking their product, we have found a polynomial $F_q$ of degree $d-1$ s.t. $F_q(q)\neq 0,\ F_q(p)=0,\forall p\in \Gamma$.

Comment: Conclusion: Do I understand it correctly that you repeat this process for all points $q$ that are not contained in $\Gamma$? Then you'd have an infinitely generated ideal with generators of degree $\leq d-1$. The variety induced by this ideal will equal $\Gamma$. Thus, the question is solved. Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: Yes. That is what I had in mind. And you are right that the construction  yields an infinite family of polynomials (assuming the field is infinite) since you need one polynomial for every $q$ not in $\Gamma$. However with a little care I think the process can be refined to yield a finite family of polynomials by some sort of induction on $n$: After you have chosen the first polynomial you have alreade "taken care" of all points outside of a finite collection of hyperplanes, so the remaining points are contained in a subvariety of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: Hence I think some sort of induction should be possible to give a finite family of polynomials - the base case being $n=2$.

Comment: By the way the argument doesn't prove that the ideal is generated by these polynomials. It only shows that  $\Gamma$ is cut out as a set by the polynomials.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I have not learned yet about the dimension of subvarieties (it's supposed to come up later in the book; which is why I was profoundly perplexed by the difficulty of the exercise as a first exercise for a beginner -- by the way, the other exercises are all within grasp for me ... as of now :) ) though what you say seems very reasonable. Anyways, thank you very much once more and have a nice day!